# Project specific dictionary from array in elasticsearch

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, elasticsearch

I have array of dictionaries in json as follows

```
{
    students : [
        {
            "name" : "abc",
            "class" : "A1"
        },
        {
            "name" : "xyz",
            "class" : "B1"
        },
        {
            "name" : "lmn",
            "class" : "B1"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want all student names which are into class "B1" in elasticsearch and I have tried using following elasticsearch query

```
{
    "query" : { "term" : { "students.class.raw": "B1" } }
}
```

but it has given output

```
[
    {
        "name" : "abc",
        "class" : "A1"
    },
    {
        "name" : "xyz",
        "class" : "B1"
    },
    {
        "name" : "lmn",
        "class" : "B1"
    }
]
```

Projected all fields into array.

Get query for all student names which are into class "B1" in elasticsearch and output should be

```
[
    {
        "name" : "xyz",
        "class" : "B1"
    },
    {
        "name" : "lmn",
        "class" : "B1"
    }
]
```

I need help to resolve this problem.

Thanks in advance.